# Get all details of child with relation of its parents in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parent-child

**Cat and sub category Table (cat_tbl)**   :

```
id | cat_n    | parent_id
1  |   cat    |  0
2  |   dog    |  0
3  |   tiger  |  2
4  |   lion   |  0
5  |   abc    |  0
6  |   bcd    |  3
```

**Now i have a product table as below (prod_tbl) :**

```
id  | pwght | cid  |  cpid 
10  |  1.2  |  1   |   0
11  |  2.4  |  2   |   0
12  |  3.4  |  2   |   0
13  |  4.5  |  6   |   3
```

**and user final weight product table is below (userprod_tbl) :**

```
id | pwght | cid  |  cpid | prod_id ( is above prod_tbl primary id )
1  |  1.1  |  1   |   0   |  10
2  |  2.3  |  2   |   0   |  11
3  |  3.1  |  3   |   2   |  12
4  |  4.0  |  6   |   3   |  13
```

**RESULT : ( OUTPUT WHICH I WANT ) IS comparison of prod_tbl with userprod_tbl as below :**

```
 Prod tbl                  Userprod tbl

 cat  1.2                  cat                 1.1

 dog  2.4                  dog   --     --     2.3
 dog  3.4                  dog  tiger   --     3.1
 dog  4.5                  dog  tiger  bcd     4.0
```

Hence in above result  2.4,3.4,4.5 are belong to Parent id **2**

**But i am getting as below**

```
 Prod tbl                  Userprod tbl

 cat  1.2                  cat                 1.1

 dog  2.4                  dog   --     --     2.3
 dog  3.4                  dog  tiger   --     3.1
```

in above result ***i am not getting 4.5 value*** ,as 4.5 has 6,3 relation from above prod table but its parent of id **2**

**Below is my query which i have return:**

```
SELECT pt.pwght , upt.pwght ,ct.cat_n,uct.cat_n,umct.cat_n
FROM prod_tbl AS pt
LEFT JOIN userprod_tbl AS upt ON (pt.id = upt.prod_id)
LEFT JOIN cat_tbl AS ct ON pt.packet_id = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cat_tbl AS uct ON upt.packet_id = uct.id
LEFT JOIN cat_tbl AS umct ON upt.parent_packet_id = umct.id
```

Please let me know what is missing
Thanks

Comment: If I'm not wrong then correct me How would you get `dog  4.5` if you have `13  |  4.5  |  6   |   3` this value within your **prod_tbl** having **cid** **6** instead of **2**

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Aparently cid 6 has parent 3, which has parent 2. He wants it to go up the ladder twice. Not gonna happen.

Comment: @ havenard , thats great u r right... but why not happen ... can u guide me please what is wrong ...also  parent 2 have 3 ,6 but it may have more level ...please help me

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem I think.

```
SELECT pt.pwght AS prod_pwght, upt.pwght AS userprod_pwght ,
       ct.cat_n AS prod_catName,uct.cat_n AS Userprod_catName
FROM prod_tbl AS pt
LEFT JOIN userprod_tbl AS upt ON pt.id = upt.prod_id
LEFT JOIN cat_tbl AS ct ON pt.cid = ct.id
LEFT JOIN cat_tbl AS uct ON upt.cid = uct.id;
```

here is working fiddle for you - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9568a/1

Comment: @ nilesh thanks for query ...but as said by " Havenard " parent id 2 may have more levels  as of 6,3 also  may be some other parent id like 1 or other may have same level ...so at same time i need to have group of main parent with there child level

Comment: hey i did what u said...but not working :( .. i know in ur fiddle its working but at my side noo not working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot translate recursion into SQL. You could make your query increasingly complex to cover this recursion up to a determined number of levels, but not to an undetermined number, and doing that is very slow and completely unecessary.

I suggest you fetch `cat_tbl` to your script and compute this category ladder localy instead of imposing that on MySQL.

Example (Please note I'm just writing this without testing anything):

```
$cat_tree = [];

$res = $mysql->query('SELECT id, cat_n, parent_id FROM cat_tbl');
while ($row = $res->fetch_row())
    $cat_tree[$row[0]] = [$row[1], $row[2]];

function get_tree($cid)
{
    global $cat_tree;

    $result = [$cat_tree[$cid][1]];
    while ($cat_tree[$cid][2])
    {
        $cid = $cat_tree[$cid][2];
        $result[] = $cat_tree[$cid][1];
    }
    return array_reverse($result);
}

$res = $mysql->query('SELECT pt.id, pt.cid, pt.pwght, ut.cid, ut.pwght FROM prod_tbl pt INNER JOIN userprod_tbl ut ON pt.id = u.prod_id');
while ($row = $res->fetch_row())
{
    $ptree = get_tree($row[1]);
    $utree = get_tree($row[3]);
    printf("%s | %f | %s | %s\n", $ptree[0], $row[2], implode(', ', $utree), $row[4]);
}
```

This should output something like:

```
cat | 1.2 | cat | 1.1
dog | 2.4 | dog | 2.3
dog | 3.4 | dog, tiger | 3.1
dog | 4.5 | dog, tiger, bcd | 4.0
```

Comment: hey havenard , your right parent id 2 may have more child or subchild ....can you please tell me in query note :) thanks

Comment: U means to say by single cat and sub cat ( like where cid = 2 ...etc ) ? ... if so then its no..i need to show all records with comparison of  prod and userprod table  in single query ... and if i have understand some wrong then please guide me plss

Comment: @user3209031 I have updated my answer with some code.

Comment: HEY IS ITS POSSIBLE ,, IF I MAKE A ANOTHER COLUMN  ( like main_cid ) in both table prod and userprod ..and pass 2 id in it ..so that with each record i will have my parent id to it ....

Comment: @user3209031 If your goal is to obtain the topmost category id instead of the entire tree, that would solve the problem.

Comment: @ havenard sir , actually i need to get record of all  prod with comparsion of userprod  with there PARENT ID (  like in above ex: parent id 2 has child 3 , and 3 has child 6 , but 6 also belong to 2 ... same way they may have more parent id like 2 in my table ) so i need all records in single query with both table.. and thanks for reply sir ..

Comment: @user3209031 Unclear what you are asking. But my script should produce the desired output if thats of any help.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation sir... checking u r script

Comment: sir i tried above script ,,but the result is not coming properly ... but lucky the script u put first is working some what ... but sir i need result to be come with order or parent id ( 2,3,6) but i am getting  cat id  1,2,3,4,5,6,7 like this order so can you please tell me how i can put parent with all its child in same order thats 1 after another ....thanks